# Unexpected character in prerequisites

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

From when I installed the new Xcode 11 I have the issue that the project doesn't open because of permission and also I have 4 errors that I hadn't before. I try cleaning the deveripet folder but nothing. Do you have some idea?[image]

Comment: Did you clean your derived data?

Comment: Yes I cleaned the derived data but nothing

Comment: Did this happen after a merge

Answer (score 10):

One of the files or directories in your project contains a colon character, which is invalid for the new Xcode build system.  Remove the colon and it should work.

Comment: How can I find it?

Comment: @Matteo The image you posted shows the name `CompanyController:Accorcio`. I assume that's a `.swift` file.

Comment: You don't need to delete controllers, just remove the `:` from the source file names and directories.

Comment: By removing `:` did the trick. It cost me almost 2 day!!:0

Answer (score 1):

In my case the colon was present in the scheme name, so the folder generated into derived data was named with the scheme name containing the colon.
So fixed just renaming the Xcode scheme removing the colon.

Comment: Same here, 4 years later. XCode really feels like Howl's Moving Castle. I wonder if they think it's a finished product.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Same Problem with xcode 10 project ,in my case I just installed my pods again with pod install and it worked for me .