# After update, Xcode 15 suddenly stopped compile a project for Arm64, with error Unblock downstream dependents

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, xcode15

I have a project based on SwiftData in Xcode 15 for iOS 17. Since is Xcode updated from beta to release, the project stopped compiling for ARM 64 (i.e. for App Store) with the error "Unblock downstream dependents".

Here's the error message:
error reading dependency file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-eykxkvtdjlpstcgqkmwtxzjprzrp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/AppName.build/Release-iphoneos/AppName.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppName-master.d': missing ':' following rule

It still successfully compiles for Simulator and on real device though.
And the project doesn't have any external dependencies, btw.

The only solutions I found on the Internet is deleting Deriverd Data – but it wasn't helpful.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Edit your question and replace the image with the actual text of the image. Images can’t be searched or referenced, they are harder to read, and they are harder to post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected character in prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081108/unexpected-character-in-prerequisites)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved by removing ":" from all file/project names and clearing deriverd data