# error reading dependency file '': unexpected character in prerequisites

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, archive, xcode15

I am **archiving** my project and getting error.

The exact error I am getting is:

> error reading dependency file '/Users/qaziammararshad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayDate-ezhxlfmvmujfscbpjogpkbmuvmwl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PlayDate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PlayDate.build/Release-iphoneos/PlayDate.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PlayDate-master.d': unexpected character in prerequisites

The solutions I tried:

- Clean Build
- Delete Derive Data

These solutions did not work in my case.

This is the image for it:

[image: error image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected character in prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081108/unexpected-character-in-prerequisites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clear the issue by checking all of your files for a colon in the file name. If I am right, the master has all files' names in a text and one of the files has the colon in there which is causing the problem.

DIdn't Have To Clean Derived Data.
You Can Check Here As Well: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144629/after-update-xcode-15-suddenly-stopped-compile-a-project-for-arm64-with-error)